# Access public address of a DC/OS service

Tags: marathon, dcos

I deployed a service on DC/OS with the following config

[image]

when I access this address (http://eureka.marathon.l4lb.thisdcos.directory:8761/) it says the site can't be reached, although all services are healthy on my dashboard.
How can I access the public IP of the service?

I don't know if it is related or not but when I look into the load balancing config of my public slaves, I get `0 of 2 instances in service`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<vip-name>.marathon.l4lb.thisdcos.directory:<vip-port>` is the internal named virtual IP, configured with the `VIP_0` env var in your example.

VIPs are not externally exposed. They are made possible via layer 4 name and IP mapping performed by DC/OS components on each node.

In order to expose a public address you have a few options:

1. [Deploy your app on a public node](https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/usage/tutorials/public-app/)
2. [Deploy Marathon_LB on a public node and configure your app to be exposed via a virtual host](https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/usage/service-discovery/marathon-lb/marathon-lb-basic-tutorial/)
3. Set up your own reverse proxy on a public node
4. Make all your private nodes publicly accessible and then use the host agent node IP and host port
5. If your app is a Mesos framework, it can register a `webui_url` for [administrative access via the admin router](https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/development/dcos-integration/#framework-web-ui-url).

Comment: My app was deployed in a public node, but there is no easy way to get the external address. I'm trying the marathon-lb but the documentation is everything but clear :(

Comment: What "load balancing config of my public slaves" are you talking about?

Comment: marathon-lb...it is quite confusing his configuration

Answer (score 0):

in windows command prompt(administrator mode) type "nslookup domain of service".
In your case "nslookup eureka.marathon.l4lb.thisdcos.directory". In your case it will provide all instance ip address.

if your service deployed properly it will give you all instance ip address.